# lineBreakMode: unrecognised selector exception in MonoTouch when setting ParagraphStyle

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, mono, xamarin

subject says it all, so i will comment after showing a code:

```
        var attr = new CTStringAttributes ();
        attr.Font = new CTFont("Parangon110C", 11);

        var paragraph = new CTParagraphStyleSettings ();
        paragraph.Alignment = CTTextAlignment.Justified;
        attr.ParagraphStyle = new CTParagraphStyle(paragraph);

        DescLabel.AttributedText = new NSAttributedString(billboard.Desc, attr);
```

so after running this code i get an exception

```
Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSInvalidArgumentException Reason: -[__NSCFType lineBreakMode]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xe5a4db0
```

i've figured out that it only appears when i set up the attr.ParagraphStyle. but when it is null, everything is ok (except i can't get text formatted my way lol).
after executing a string

```
DescLabel.AttributedText = new NSAttributedString(billboard.Desc, attr);
```

debugger shows the exception text in Size property of DescLabel.AttributedText.

i suspect, this is a bug in  CTStringAttributes or CTParagraphStyle.
i've found there [CoreText repository](https://github.com/mono/maccore/tree/master/src/CoreText) but can't say what's wrong till now

also, little later, i've found a [bugreport](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=8940) where someone complaints his stuff not working. but after correcting an obvious error in code (lucky guy), he's not commenting anymore, so the conclusion is: he'd got this working.
but his code is similar to mine..

please help me to resolve this or to find workaround. (UIParagraphStyle is not working either, it says that UIParagraphStyleSettings.LineBreakMode setter is not implemented)

Comment: the sources you're pointing to are for mac, not monotouch, but that's not very important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently from IOS 6 and upwards you have to use UIKits NSParagraphStyle for this instead of the CoreText CTParagraphStyle

```
var parstyle = new MonoTouch.UIKit.NSMutableParagraphStyle ();
parstyle.Alignment = MonoTouch.UIKit.UITextAlignment.Justified;
var att = new NSMutableAttributedString (billboard.Desc);
att.AddAttribute (
    MonoTouch.UIKit.UIStringAttributeKey.ParagraphStyle,
    parstyle,
    new NSRange (0, att.Length)
);
att.AddAttribute (
    MonoTouch.UIKit.UIStringAttributeKey.Font,
    MonoTouch.UIKit.UIFont.FromName ("Parangon110C", 11),
    new NSRange (0, att.Length)
    );
DescLabel.AttributedText = att;
```

there is also a convenient constructor for NSAttributedString to do this:

```
var parstyle = new MonoTouch.UIKit.NSMutableParagraphStyle ();
parstyle.Alignment = MonoTouch.UIKit.UITextAlignment.Justified;

DescLabel.AttributedText = new NSAttributedString (
                str: billboard.Desc,
                font: MonoTouch.UIKit.UIFont.FromName ("Parangon110C", 11),
                paragraphStyle: parstyle);
```

Comment: ok, thank, i eventually came up with this code, because autocompletion works with this best way and it's more readable to my taste: 
   NSMutableParagraphStyle parstyle = new NSMutableParagraphStyle ();
   parstyle.Alignment = UITextAlignment.Center;
   attr.ParagraphStyle = parstyle;
   DescLabel.AttributedText = new NSAttributedString(billboard.Desc, attr);
i did this after complainting for bug [that was confirmed](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=15402) . i will mark your comment as the answere in case people will stuck upon the same problem. cheers!

Comment: i wish this issue was documented anyway. and the fact that i can youse it now doesn't get me to the point, actually. justified alignment is just not working. left, right, center are working. but text is simply not justified. may be apple means something of their own when using this term.. (sorry can't thumb up your comment, too low reputation ^^)